# How to Categorize an iOS app as "AR" in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, augmented-reality, arkit

I have an ARKit Game available on the App Store but I would like it to be categorized as an `AR Game`. Currently I have categorized it as `Game.Simulation` and `Game.Action` as I can not understand if it's possible to categorize it as `Game.AR`.

Is it possible?

The only categories I can select from are the following:
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for now, there is **no AR Games category** in the App Store right now and you cannot define custom categories for your apps.

The closest subcategory to that would be Simulation.